# want to substract two dates from two different tables, getting syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
select to_date(to_char(MIN (logical_date), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD')from table_1 
     - to_date(to_char(MIN (due_date) ,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD') FROM table_2
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Hence your question does not either.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Let suppose I have D1 date in table_1 and D2 date in table_2 then how can I find out no of days from these two dates (D1 and D2). if D1=1/05/2019 and D2=15/05/2019 then result should be D1-D2=15

Comment: The structure of your query doesn't match [the legal syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm), so not surprising you get an error, but it would be helpful to say *what* error you get - in this case, presumably it's "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" ?

Comment: A single `select` statement can't have two separate `from` clauses. Before learning about date arithmetic, it seems you need to spend more time with the very basic elements of SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could subtract the results of two subqueries, each of which gets the minimum date from one of the tables; with the overall query run against `dual` (the built-in single-row table that's quite useful for this sort of thing):

```
-- CTEs for your sample data
with table_1 (logical_date) as (select date '2019-05-01' from dual),
  table_2 (due_date) as (select date '2019-05-15' from dual)
-- actual query
select (select to_date(to_char(min(logical_date), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD') from table_1)
  - (select to_date(to_char(min(due_date) ,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD') from table_2)
  as diff
from dual;

      DIFF
----------
       -14
```

But you don't need to convert to and from strings, you can just do:

```
select (select min(logical_date) from table_1) - (select min(due_date) from table_2) as diff
from dual;
```

unless your dates have non-midnight time components, in which case you'll get a fractional number of days in your result; to get whole days only either round/trunc/floor/ceil the result, or use `trunc()` to set both time components to midnight before you subtract - which you do depends on how you want to handle those fractional days.

If you're expecting that difference to be -15, then subtract one from the result. If you expect a positive value then reverse the order of the subqueries, and add one instead.